# Haskell Pipes -- Having a pipe consume what it yields (itself)

Tags: haskell, pipe, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to write a webscraper using Pipes and I've come to the part of following scraped links. I have a `process` function that downloads a url, finds links, and yields them.

```
process :: Pipe Item Item (StateT CState IO) ()
 ....
    for (each links) yield
 ....
```

Now I want to some how recursively follow these links, threading the StateT through. I realize there is probably doing something more idiomatic then using a single pipe for the bulk of the scraper (especially as I start adding more features), I'm open for suggestions. I'm probably going to have to rethink the design when I consider multithreading w/ shared state anyways.

Comment: Matter of preference, but I'd probably have `process :: (MonadState CState m, MonadIO m) => Pipe Item Item m ()`. Not much code change (probably), more readable, and abstracts away the implementation details of your monad stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect a `Pipe a b m r` to a side-effect through the `m` parameter, which swaps out which `Monad` the pipe is operating over. You can use this to requeue links by connecting the downstream end of your pipe to another pipe that sticks the links in a queue and connecting the upstream end of your pipe to a pipe that reads links from the queue.

Our goal is to write

```
import Pipes

loopLeft :: Monad m => Pipe (Either l a) (Either l b) m r -> Pipe a b m r
```

We'll take a pipe whose downstream output, `Either l b`, is either an `Left l` to send back upstream or a `Right b` to send downstream, and send the `l`s back in the upstream input `Either l a`, which is either a queued up `Left l` or a `Right a` coming from upstream. We'll connect the `Left l`s together to make a pipe that only sees `a`s coming from upstream and only yields `b`s headed downstream.

At the downstream end we'll push the `l`s from `Left l` onto a stack. We `yield` the `r`s from `Right r` downstream.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

pushLeft :: Monad m => Pipe (Either l a) a (StateT [l] m) r
pushLeft = forever $ do
    o <- await
    case o of
        Right a -> yield a
        Left l -> do
            stack <- lift get
            lift $ put (l : stack)
```

At the upstream end we'll look for something on top of the stack to `yield`. If there isn't one, we'll `await` for a value from upstream and `yield` it.

```
popLeft :: Monad m => Pipe a (Either l a) (StateT [l] m) r
popLeft = forever $ do
    stack <- lift get
    case stack of
        [] -> await >>= yield . Right
        (x : xs) -> do
            lift $ put xs
            yield (Left x)
```

Now we can write `loopLeft`. We compose the upstream and downstream pipes together with pipe composition `popLeft >-> hoist lift p >-> pushLeft`. The `hoist lift` turns a `Pipe a b m r` into a `Pipe a b (t m) r`. The [`distribute`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes-Lift.html#v:distribute) turns a `Pipe a b (t m) r` into a `t (Pipe a b m) r`. To get back to a `Pipe a b m r` we run the whole `StateT` computation starting with an empty stack `[]`. In `Pipes.Lift` there's a nice name [`evalStateP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes-Lift.html#v:evalStateP) for the combination of `evalStateT` and `distribute`.

```
import Pipes.Lift

loopLeft :: Monad m => Pipe (Either l a) (Either l b) m r -> Pipe a b m r
loopLeft p = flip evalStateT [] . distribute $ popLeft >-> hoist lift p >-> pushLeft
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
import Pipes

type Url = String

getLinks :: Url -> IO [Url]
getLinks = undefined

crawl :: MonadIO m => Pipe Url Url m a
crawl = loop []
  where
    loop [] = do url <- await; loop [url]
    loop (url:urls) = do
      yield url
      urls' <- liftIO $ getLinks url
      loop (urls ++ urls')
```

You can achieve DFS or BFS depending on how you combine `url'` with `urls`.